# JMeter response times and the response times I get on my server are very different

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, jsr223

I wrote a script with JSR223 Sampler. It sends certain requests to my server. I also log response times on my server. But there are serious differences between the response times I get in the log and the response times given to me by JMeter. What appears to be 60ms in my log, appears to be around 200ms in JMeter reports.

Additionally, what should I do for samplers for which I do not want the response time to be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is you who "wrote a script" this should be a question to you.

I can only assume that JMeter elapsed time includes the time which is needed to establish the connection and the time for the request and response to travel back and forth. See `Connect Time` and `Latency` terms in the [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

If you don't want to record the sample result you can call [`SampleResult.setIgnore()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore()) function anywhere in your script.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you.
So what should I do if I want to ignore only one row?
For example, I have codes like c = a.b() c.k() below.
I want to ignore the a.b() line so that it does not calculate the time.

Comment: You need to measure the time of the `a.b()` line and subtract it from the overall response time for example in [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor). You can get the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) object via [`prev` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) and then overwrite the elapsed time of the JSR223 Sampler with the calculated value.

Comment: Thank you, as you said, I saved some time, almost close to the time in my LOG file. "vars.getObject" takes too much time. I have to use it in the same JSR223 Sampler. But I don't want "vars.getObject" to be included in the duration.

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to suggest what to do without knowing what you're trying to achieve. `vars.getObject()` itself should be very fast, but it depends on the nature of the "object". You can move this function into [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), it's duration is not included into the sampler. Another approach is preparing any test data in the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your support. My problem is largely solved now.